# reduce width of body and add a HTML background

Tags: html, background, width

I am trying to reduce the width of my body by putting it in a container so I can see two stripes on each sides of the body (which I assume would be the background of my HTML)??

Here is an example of what I want: http://www.colingrist.com/
.. When expanding the window, you can see that the body only takes the middle of the page and you can then see the background of the HTML...

Should I adjust the margin or padding of my body or of the container?

Comment: Based on the implementation of the website you provide, you should put a background on the `<body>` and add right/left margins to your container.

Comment: so i added a white background on my <body> and a grey background on my <html>. Then I added a margin of -30% on left and right side of my <body> but I still cant see the grey color of my <html> background... and now the right side is way more wide than my left side, on the side of my .hero ...

Comment: Positive margins on both sides. Negative margin would push the edges of the container off of the screen, which is the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a section or div tag like the example you provided.

For example,

```
<body>
  <div>
    ..Your Content..
  </div>
</body>
```

and in your css file, you can use the following:

```
div{
  width: /*your specified width here*/
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

The margin: 0 auto will center the HTML element in your page and prevent it from stretching. In the website you provided, the author used a section instead of a div.

If you want your website to be responsive, I recommend you use Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Also, avoid putting content outside the body tag. Content outside the body tag isn't valid HTML.